# What expression is analogous to "whoops a daisy"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections

Is there an expression in French that is analogous to the English *whoops a daisy*? I'm asking about an old-fashioned expression that would be used nowadays to express having made a small mistake, for example, dropping something on the floor.

I found on [this forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whoopsie-daisy.1655095/) that it might be **houp-là**, but I'm not sure if this expression can be also used in the small mistake context, or is just a reaction for lifting something.

Comment: It is an interjection, so to find its equivalent, first locates its context, and its field of use !

Comment: Informations sur l'[origine](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/ups-a-daisy.html).

Answer (score 4):

My grandmother would use something like

> Flûte !
>
> Sapristi !

Answer (score 3):

Often found in Hergé's Tintin:

> Saperlipopette!

might have this old-school sound to it.

Answer (score -1):

To do it in pure Gallic fashion:

> MERDE ALORS !

Comment: I do not actually agree with that. Originally, *whoops a daisy* is used in a context with children. I would personally avoid *merde alors* with children. Would it sound more Gallic.